# Spring NamedJDBCTemplate gives uncategorized SQLException for SQL while executing insert statement

Tags: java, spring

Below error is coming while trying to insert using spring namedJDBCTemplate.

Same code is working in my local windows machine (deployed in jboss server).
But is not working in a UNIX box(deployed in Jboss server).
Data source is created by jboss server and ojdbc6.jar is used for it.

The number parameters sent in the statement are same as what need to be inserted.
Any idea on this ?

Code : `

```
@RestController
public class Test_A {

@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@RequestMapping(value="/addTable_A", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Response> addTable_A(@RequestBody RequestForm[] forms) {      

    TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : rowData.entrySet()) {
            parameters = parameters.addValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(),Types.VARCHAR);
            getLog().writeLocation(FileLogger.ALWAYS, loggingMethod + "KEY : "+entry.getKey()+" , VALUE : "+entry.getValue());              
        }
        getLog().writeLocation(FileLogger.ALWAYS, loggingMethod + " Before Insert -- QUERY USED :: >> " + query.toString());

        int res = 0;
        try{
            res = namedJdbcTemplate.update(query.toString(), parameters, holder, new String[] { "id" });
        }catch(Throwable t){
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String  exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            getLog().writeLocation(FileLogger.ALWAYS, loggingMethod + "In exception bloack of insert 3.3"+exceptionAsString);
        }finally{
            transactionManager.commit(status);  
        }           
    }
}
```

`

Error : `

21 09:57:09.448 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : A , VALUE : A1

21 09:57:09.448 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : B , VALUE : B1

21 09:57:09.449 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : C , VALUE : C1

21 09:57:09.449 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : D , VALUE : D1

21 09:57:09.449 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : E , VALUE : E1

21 09:57:09.449 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : F , VALUE : F1

21 09:57:09.449 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : ID , VALUE :

21 09:57:09.450 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : G , VALUE : G1

21 09:57:09.450 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : H , VALUE : H1

21 09:57:09.450 com.test.Test_A[278]: addTable_A : KEY : I , VALUE : I1

21 09:57:09.451 com.test.Test_A[287]: validateInputData :  Before Insert -- QUERY USED :: >> Insert into table_A (A,B,C,D,E,F,ID,G,H,I) values (:A,:B,:C,:D,:E,:F,:ID,:G,:H,:I)

21 09:57:09.559 com.test.Test_A[297]: validateInputData : In exception bloack of insert 3.3org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [Insert into table_A (A,B,C,D,E,F,ID,G,H,I,J) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:900)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:318)

`

Comment: Post the complete code, including "parameters" and "query"

Answer (score 0):

You specified that in a environment it works fine, while in another it doesn't.
First thing to do in such a case is explicitly specify parameters' types.

As `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate#update` accept a `SqlParamaterSource`, I suppose you're using a `MapSqlParameterSource`, therefore you might want to use the

```
addValue(String paramName, Object value, int sqlType)
```

method to add a parameter. You'll find SQL types under `java.sql.Types`.

---

Anyway, as I wrote in the comments, post the executed SQL statement and the parameters' map.

Comment: But both environments connect to same DB.

Comment: @skt100 well, it doesn't cost a lot trying this out. Since the exception isn't well defined, we need to proceed by exclusion.

Comment: Insert into table_A (A,B,C,D,E,F,ID,G,H,I,J) 
values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate)

Params :

 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
 "D"
 "E"
 "F"
 "ID" 
 "G"
 "H"
 "I"

Comment: added below block also,                                                                          
     parameters = parameters.addValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(),Types.VARCHAR);                                                                                 it did not work, but i keep trying other things as well

Comment: @skt100 aren't you using placeholders? Question marks are for the standard JDBC Template

Comment: I have edited code snippet and error block a little more , so you can understand well on the issue

Comment: I need the ID generated back in my code to do other operation, But will try without that and let you know.

Comment: Hello LppEdd, ur suggestion helped, after removing keyHolder , i am able to add, But now i need to figure out, how i can get it added with the Keyholder too. anyways  appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @skt100 That's strange however. Maybe try debugging KeyHolder and see what happens inside. I'll give it a look too